# Using the mongodb $slice feature in php

Tags: php, mongodb

How would I translated this shell to php:

```
db.products.find({}, {comments:{$slice: 5}}
```

Comment: Be more specific please. Show us some research effort as well.

Comment: I dont understand how to do the equivalent in php and I cant find a tutorial on using the slice feature in php.

Comment: That is not using the $slice operator

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried?

This looks like a pretty simple case:

```
db->products->find( array(), array('comments' => array( '$slice' => 5 ) ) );
```

Is there something specifically wrong with the simple translation?

Comment: I think he's just being lazy :)

Comment: I think it is $slice operator for projection. So that, in a program using MongoDB PHP library you should use: 
.....->find( [ ], [ 'projection' => ['comments' => [ '$slice'=>5 ] ] ] )